# why gram matrix row sum is always 0

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In my lecture slides of PCA its mentioned that the rows of gram matrix sum to zero. Now I understand what is a gram matrix but I don't understand how exactly do rows always sum to zero and what does it mean?

Comment: The claim is false. The Gram matrix of an orthonormal basis is the identity matrix. Its rows sum to one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoever told you this probably might have formed the Gram matrix in the wrong way.

Suppose we have a data matrix $X\in M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$, where each row of $X$ represents a data point (hence there are $m$ data points in $\mathbb R^n$; usually $m$ is much larger than $n$). In PCA, we first de-mean the data, so that the new data have mean zero. In other words, we first calculate the mean row vector $\bar{x}=\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^mX_{i\ast}$ of all rows of $X$, then subtract this sample mean from each row of $X$ to form a demeaned data matrix $Y$ such that $Y_{i\ast}=X_{i\ast}-\bar{x}$. Put it another way, we translate the centroid of the data set to the the origin.

At this point, we do have $\sum_iY_{i\ast}=0$. That is, all **rows** of $Y$ sum to the zero **vector**, because they have zero mean. (Note: such wording can be confusing at times. That the *rows* of $Y$ sum to the zero *vector* actually means that all *column sums* of $Y$ are zero. Please don't mistake this with the statement that *"all row sums of $Y$ are zero"*.)

Since all rows of $Y$ add up to the zero row vector, so do all rows of the Gram matrix $YY^T$. As $YY^T$ is symmetric, its columns sum to the zero column vector too.

However, in PCA, the Gram matrix we use is **not** $YY^T\in M_m(\mathbb R)$, but $V=Y^TY\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ (which, up to a factor $\frac1m$ or $\frac1{m-1}$, is the covariance matrix for the $n$ features of a random data point). Unless all your data points happen to fall on an affine hyperplane, the rows of $V$ usually would never sum to zero.